# Why document.getElementById() function is not present inside the window.document object?

Tags: javascript

I want to know why `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByClassName()` like functions are not present inside the `window.document` object. Am I missing something?

Comment: These are DOM methods. Why should they be part of the global execution context?

Comment: The way you are asking this is strange because the global `document` is `window.document`. Thus the answer as you phrased the question is they are available in `window.document`

Comment: What led you to believe that the functions are not present? They clearly are.

Comment: @Pointy actually I forgot about the prototype inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Because they work at the document level, not the window level. That's just where they fit. So they're defined on the [`Document` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). (Some, like `geElementsByClassName`, `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll` and such are *also* defined at the [`Element` level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/); they work just within that element.)

One aspect of that is that you can use more than one document. For instance, `DOMParser` creates documents:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    `<div id="x">hi</div>`,
    "text/html"
);

// The following shows a div with "hi" in it
console.log(doc.getElementById("x"));

// The following shows `null`, because there isn't any `id="x"` element
// in `document`
console.log(document.getElementById("x"));
```

While you could have a `window.getElementById` that just turned around and did `window.document.getElementById`, there's no good reason to have that. It fits better on `document`.